# handling broadcast receiver

Tags: android

I have an app which has MainActivity(without gui.. please just flow with it:) )

now this MainActivity running a service, this service using sendBroadcast() in order to comunnicate with the MainActivity..
now ofcourse i need to **registerReceiver** in the **onResume**() of the MainActivity.

but i also need to add **unregisterReceiver**(receiver) in the **onDestroy**() of the MainActivity.

problem is: when i first start that app i need it to up the service, and i dont want the user to lose focus, so i press **finish**() after i`am starting the service.. but then auto invoked also 
unregisterReceiver(receiver).. and this is not good for me.. i get error it's said it couldnt find any registerd reciver.

so i fixed it by delete this line.. but i am sure its going to 'revenege' me in the future, when/where could i have problem if i wont use unregisterReceiver(receiver)..  at the onDestroy()

mybe i should remove it (instead of delete it) to onPause()?

thanks,

ray.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling bindService within onStart(), unbindService() within onStop(), registerReciever() within onResume() and unregisterReceiver() within onPause().

You might have a look at a piece of my working code. Maybe it can help you find your solution.

In the real project I commented the following:

bindService(new Intent(test1.this, MyService.class), mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

unbindService(mServiceConnection);

and all of the mServiceConnection declaration.

I did it because it's actually a background service starting on system boot time. Otherwise they should not be commented.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    bindService(new Intent(test1.this, MyService.class), mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    getApplicationContext().startService(serviceIntent);
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    unbindService(mServiceConnection); 
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(MyService.BROADCAST_ACTION));
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}

private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRecieve");
        constantCursor.requery(); // service finished its job, refresh ListView         
    }
};



private ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        mService = ((MyService.LocalBinder)service).getService();
        Log.d(TAG, "onServiceConnected");
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        // This is called when the connection with the service has been
        // unexpectedly disconnected -- that is, its process crashed.
        mService = null;
        Log.d(TAG, "onServiceDisconnected");
    }

};
```

Comment: problem is that i use registerReceiver(..) only at onResume() and if put finish(); at the end of onCreate(..) in nevers get to it. i need to register this somehow before. 
this is what i get:
MainActivity$1@4359dab0 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?